# Display total in views

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7 with views 3.

I am listing the fee of students in a view developed using views 3. How can I show the total of fee for all records displayed at bottom as Total Fee. I tried Views_calc module, but this module is with some errors and notices.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: probably you should look for a programming way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this hook

```
function fee_management_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if($view->name == 'payment_schedules' && ($view->current_display == 'receive_payments')) {    
        $total_payable_amount = 0;
        foreach($view->result as $key => $payment) {
            $total_payable_amount += $payment->fee_schedule_instalments_amount;
        }
        $view->attachment_after = "<div> Total Payable Amount: $total_payable_amount</div>"; // does not work with fee_management_views_post_render

    }
}
```